# atomic store operation implementation under visual 2013

Tags: c++, atomic

```
var_.store(value, std::memory_order_relaxed);

inline void _Store_relaxed_4(volatile _Uint4_t *_Tgt, _Uint4_t _Value)
    {   /* store _Value atomically with relaxed memory order */
 #if defined(_M_ARM)
    __iso_volatile_store32((volatile int *)_Tgt, _Value);

 #else
    *_Tgt = _Value;
 #endif
    }
```

How ***_Tgt = _Value;** can be atomic ?

Comment: That is the implementation's responsibility. What is your programming question?

Comment: Because that's for x86/x86_64.

Comment: a pointer dereferencement + assignement is atomic under x86/x86_64?

Comment: A word-aligned word-sized store is atomic in x86/x86_64

Comment: *_Tgt = _Value; is only a store operation ? I believed this is a read (or thing for deference the pointer) + a store

Comment: Yes, *_Tgt = _Value is a store-only operation at *_Tgt. In constrast, things such as (*_Tgt)++ is read-modify-store. And the store is atomic if its address is divisible by its size (naturally aligned). It's aligned because there's some compiler pragma stuff in the type definition.